# How do I add @login_required decorator to the builtin django's logout view?

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to add @login_required to the logout view, but how?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent a logged-out user from accessing the logout view?

Comment: Add your urls.py so that we can build up on your code

Answer (score 0):

The benefits of this solution seem dubious, but try this:

```
admin.site.logout = login_required(admin.site.logout)
```